# Hapi/Joi Validation For Number Fails

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, joi, hapi

I am trying to validate number value which will include integer as well as float values. Following is my implementation for the same.

**Joi Schema.**

```
const numcheckschema = Joi.object().keys({
  v1:Joi.number().empty("").allow(null).default(99999),
  v2:Joi.number().empty("").allow(null).default(99999),
  v3:Joi.number().empty("").allow(null).default(99999)
})
```

**Object**

```
objnum={
  v1:"15",
  v2:"13.",
  v3:"15"
}

objValidated = Joi.validate(objnum, numcheckschema);
console.log(objValidated);
```

When i execute the above mentioned code I get an error

> ValidationError: child "v2" fails because ["v2" must be a number]

as per the documentation when we tries to pass any **numeric value** as a **string** it converts the values to number but here in this case my value is **13.** which is not able to convert into number and throwing an error.

Is there any way by which we can convert this value to **13.0**

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex in order to match numbers with a dot, for instance:

```
Joi.string().regex(/\d{1,2}[\,\.]{1}/)
```

And then combine both validations using **Joi.alternatives**:

```
Joi.alternatives().try([
      Joi.number().empty("").allow(null),
      Joi.string().regex(/\d{1,2}[\,\.]{1}/)
])
```

However, I think you may need to convert the payload to number using **Number(string value)**. You need to check the payload type, if it isn't a Number, you need to convert it.

If you want to know more about the regex used in the example, you can test it in here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks For the solution i will implement and check