# JavaScript NodeJS Joi validation for large numbers

Tags: node.js, numbers, joi

I am creating an application in NodeJS 12 using the Joi validation library to validate the API request body.

I am having an issue with number data types that are more than 16 digits long.

I want to validate a number that is 18 digits long.

The validation works for smaller numbers but it does not work for larger numbers. I think this might be due to a limitation with the size of numbers.

I am not able to follow the [selected answer in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134507/hapi-joi-validation-for-number-fails) because the field cannot be converted to a string. It must be processed and stored as a number in the database.

Example value:

```
999830129121239112
```

Joi validation rule

```
ExampleNumber: Joi.number().integer().max(999999999999999999).allow(null),
```

Error message:

```
{"message":"'ExampleNumber' must be a safe number at body,ExampleNumber","field":"ExampleNumber"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JS has `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` value which is equal to `9007199254740991`. So if you're using numbers in JS which are bigger than this value then you'll most likely have a different result from what you expect. For example, `999830129121239112` in your example returns `999830129121239200` in JS, so if you try to save it to your DB it will be wrong.

Means if you're planning to use such big numbers in JS you **have** to use another type, i.e. `String` or `BigInt` (starting Node v10.4, also isn't supported by all browsers - check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility))

But as I can see `BigInt` type support isn't yet implemented in Joi (judging by this closed issue: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1531) so I guess `String` is your option here.

It doesn't matter if you store the value as a string in JS, it will still be converted to a number when you save it to DB if the column is number type.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `number.unsafe()` to validate large numbers,

From the [API doc](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#numberunsafeenabled):

```
const safeNumber = Joi.number();
safeNumber.validate(90071992547409924);
// error -> "value" must be a safe number

const unsafeNumber = Joi.number().unsafe();
unsafeNumber.validate(90071992547409924);
// error -> null
// value -> 90071992547409920
```